# /dev/sda2: clean, nnn/nnn files, nnn/nnn blocks

Tags: 21.10, development

Ubuntu 21.10

So, my 240GB SSD apparently got full before shutdown and now the OS won't load.

Error screen says

```
/dev/sda2: clean xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx files xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx blocks
[FAILED] Failed to start System Logging Service
```

I have a USB with Ubuntu 21.10 loaded on it.

I do not have any space on the SSD so I could extend the partition size using GParted through Ubuntu on USB.

There was a 40GB directory I could delete.

So I

- Used USB ubuntu
- Mounted SSD
- Opened terminal and typed

  sudo nautilus

Through this I deleted the 40GB directory and rebooted.

I was still shown /dev/sda2 message

So I reused the USB to shrink the partition size from 223.07GB to 200GB via GParted (of which 178GB used).

I rebooted and saw the /dev/sda2 again.

So I reused the USB and re-extended the partition size from 200.00 to 223.07GB.

I'm still stuck at the /dev screen.

What should I do now?

Comment: You are fixing the wrong problem.  There is not enough information here to tell what the real problem is.  Maybe you "fixed" the wrong partition and there is another one that is full?  Maybe there's an error before or after the one you described that is the real error.

Comment: Are you sure it's _`[FAILED] Failed to start System Logging device`_? Because generally, the error message is *`[FAILED] Failed to start System logging service`*

Comment: @user10489 I'm afraid it boots right into this screen after displaying Ubuntu logo at start.

Comment: @Someone sorry about that. It does say System Logging Service